# Site inside .exe, everytime link is clicked, it open Internet Explorer, not Mozzila Firefox (Default Browser)

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>News n Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#636363'>
    <div class="newsEvents">
        <div id="news">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
                    <td class="title">
                        <img src="news.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://forum.tribalro.com/showthread.php?tid=1">Server Information</a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="title">
                        <img src="news.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://forum.tribalro.com/showthread.php?tid=1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="title">
                        <img src="events.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://forum.tribalro.com/showthread.php?tid=1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="title">
                        <img src="news.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://forum.tribalro.com/showthread.php?tid=1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="title">
                        <img src="news.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://forum.tribalro.com/showthread.php?tid=1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="title">
                        <img src="update.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://forum.tribalro.com/showthread.php?tid=1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="title">
                        <img src="update.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://forum.tribalro.com/showthread.php?tid=1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td class="title">
                        <img src="news.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://forum.tribalro.com/showthread.php?tid=1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr></table>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any wrong with that? Because another code do open Firefox (Default Browser) but its packed by software and they only do redirect, the only reason I don't do the same to the index.html because it's the News & Events page, must keep to update, but this one, writed in a notepad, a html file, I don't know how the hell this can happen, pretty weird.

I want to try to open the default browser instead of Internet Explorer.

Comment: can you open with firefox too ?

Comment: Why not just right click, "open with" then select the brower you want.  iIn the same view, you can set a default for that file.  Look in your defaults to see if exe files are opened with the right brower.

Comment: I don't know if I can open it with Firefox, it always use IE.
It's a game launcher, not only me using it, I want the users to get the best, most of my users won't care to really do that "open with", I also try to right click, it seems there's no open with. Open, Open in new tab, sort of :3

Answer (score 0):

They're most likely using the Internet Explorer ActiveX component for the web browser functionality. They could fix it to open links in the default browsers, but the default is simply to open IE, obviously - Chrome also opens a new tab in Chrome when you click a link, rather than using the default browser :)

This has nothing to do with HTML, so the code nor the tag aren't really appropriate. It's all about the hosting environment.

Comment: So, how I can force users to use their default browser? I don't ilke users to use IE since mostly they don't really function with my website.

Comment: @user3802781 Well, you can't. Why are they using that intermediate application? Is that your application or someone else's?